Creating VCF Card in Android
I have username and phone number from server. I want share this informations to related applications like whatsapp. But I want share with VCF card. How to create this programmatically?
I tried this but dont work properly.
`val vCard = StringBuilder()
                    vCard.append("BEGIN:VCARD\n")
                    vCard.append("VERSION:3.0\n")
                    vCard.append("FN:${"example"}\n")
                    vCard.append("ORG:${"example"}\n")
                    vCard.append("TITLE:${"example"}\n")
                    vCard.append("END:VCARD\n")

                    // Share vCard
                    val shareIntent = Intent().apply {
                        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                        type = "text/x-vcard"
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, vCard.toString())
                    }
                    // Start the share intent
                    context.startActivity(shareIntent)`


I recommend that you edit your question and explain in greater detail what "dont work properly" means. What are your specific symptoms?

I mean it works for whatsapp but dont work for  gmail  and messages. It shows string @CommonsWare
